# Pokemon go stuck on loading screen

Tags: pokemon-go

I have made two accounts and they are both stuck on the Pokeball loading screen, what I'm saying is the Pokeball keeps spinning and I cannot get on the game. I'm turning my phone into airplane mode does not work.

Comment: Why would disabling your connection to the servers help you connect to the servers?

Comment: This may sound stupid, but I was stuck a few hours. Then I rebooted my phone, and then in worked as expected.